# Command line tools are missing after install of ncache.opensource.clr40.x64.msi (version 4.9 SP1)

Tags: ncache

After installing the `.msi` from a command line with administrator privileges, I noticed that the command line tools (e.g. `clearcache.exe`, etc.) are missing from the `Program Files\NCache\bin\tools` directory. Any direction on how I can get the tools installed?

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

I've run the `.msi` in interactive mode from a command prompt that has administrative privileges.

I was expecting the command line tools like `clearcache.exe`, `addqueryindex.exe`, etc. to be present. Instead, no tools are present.

Answer (score 1):

The command tools are not available with the open source version. Here is a comparison chart that states this: http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/edition-comparison.html